# Swagger UI nested expandable groupings

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using SwaggerUI for documenting API endpoints. Currently they are grouped by controller name, in one long list. You can then expand each controller to view the operations. Everything standard.

What I would like to do, is group the controllers under common expandable groups.

So for example, you have a Pet group, which can be expanded, to reveal Cat and Dog controllers, which can then in turn be expanded to show their respective operations.

I have tried using Tags to accomplish this, but the best I can get is all operations grouped under one expandable group.

Does anyone know if this is possible with the standard swaggerUI? Or would I need to create custom HTML to accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot create nested groups with the standard swagger UI. You can however apply multiple tags on a method (e.g. Pet and Cat). In that case the method will be displayed in the Pet group and the Cat group.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Swashbuckle? What you need is to implement IDocumentFilter. Look in to the tags om the [Swagger 2.0 Spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md).

[From the docs:](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle)

**DocumentFilter**

Post-modify the entire Swagger document by wiring up one or more Document filters.

IDocumentFilter has the following interface:

```
void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer);
```

This gives full control to modify the final SwaggerDocument. You can gain additional context from the provided `SwaggerDocument` (e.g. version) and `IApiExplorer`. You should have a good understanding of the Swagger 2.0 spec. before using this option.

Comment: Yes I am using Swashbuckle. Thanks I will give this a go!