# .NET Core 2.1 Swashbuckle - group controllers by area

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle

My situation is rather simple. I have a very large .NET Core 2.1 MVC/WebApi divided into several Areas, representing different modules of my system. I use Swagger (SwashBuckle) and it works very well. My routing are like `{area}/{controller}/{action}`.

In Swagger UI, every action is grouped into the controllers (standard behaviour). My list of controllers and operations is becoming very very large and hard to grasp. Because of that, i would love if Swagger could divide my controllers into the different areas! Making it possible to collapse `area x` and every controller within `area x`.

I really miss this feature or a way to implement it myself! Any ideas are appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I've tried annotating actions with tags.

This gives me:

```
- Area 1
    - MethodFromControllerA()
    - MethodFromControllerB()
- Area 2
    - MethodFromControllerC()
    - MethodFromControllerD()
```

What i want:

```
- Area 1
    - ControllerA
        - MethodFromControllerA()
    - ControllerB
        - MethodFromControllerB()
- Area 2
    - ControllerC
        - MethodFromControllerC()
    - ControllerD
        - MethodFromControllerD()
```

**Update 2**

Another option would be to have several specifications for each of my areas. Like different Swagger UIs for every area. Possible?

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154322/adding-nested-grouping-sections-in-the-ui-for-actions-within-a-controller

Comment: Maybe checkout this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703251/swagger-ui-nested-expandable-groupings (no asp.net core though)

Comment: @B12Toaster These come close - but no specific solutions! Another options would be to have several specifications for each of my areas. Like different Swagger UI's for every area. Possible?

Comment: Depends on your api and how you want to make it accessible :) I would refrain from this as it makes it hard to search your api. Another (hacky) thing you could do is to inject js code into your swagger ui and then somehow rearrange and indent the generated html/css divs via javascript dom manipulations :D

Comment: @B12Toaster i thought of that! But i don't know how to get the information about what area controllers are in to the dom :D Any ideas??

Comment: If your controllers in the same area share the same path prefix then you could split on the "/" and base your reorderings on this prefix. Otherwise, try to somehow add meta information to your controllers or actions via annotations. ...or maybe add a Prefix to your controllers like AreaxFooController. then perform a split on the controller name in your js... Be creative :D

Comment: *I wish i was good at HTML/JS, for grouping these new DOM-objects that i could create :D*

I wish you good luck with experimenting and improving your js dom-manipulation skills ;)

Answer (score 17):

You first need to install [annotations](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations) and enable them in your startup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

Then you need to add your "area" as tag to every action.

```
[SwaggerOperation(
    Tags = new[] { "Area51" }
)]
```

When you open your swagger ui, it should be automatically grouped by tag now (per default the controller name is the chosen tag).

Further nested grouping of endpoints is currently not possible out of the box with the existing swagger ui generator.

Comment: It's true that this groups my actions in the specified tags. However, i have several controllers in each area, and i still wan't to group actions within controllers.

Comment: I don't think two-level nesting is possible.

Comment: I was afraid it was not... :-( But i could really use this for documenting our large system for my frontend developing co-workers

Comment: Hmm maybe [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/467#issuecomment-395507370) technique suits your need (or [this one](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/467#issuecomment-395749508) mentioned in the same thread)? ...having a closer look, it still looks like it is only one hierachy level.

Answer (score 2):

If your still looking to do this by area name, this is the complete code for doing it in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore:

```cs
c.OperationFilter<TagByAreaNameOperationFilter>();
```

```cs
public class TagByAreaNameOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
        {
            var areaName = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AreaAttribute), true)
                .Cast<AreaAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (areaName != null)
            {
                operation.Tags = new List<OpenApiTag> { new OpenApiTag { Name = areaName.RouteValue } };
            }
            else
            {
                operation.Tags = new List<OpenApiTag> { new OpenApiTag { Name = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName } };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This groups the actions, not the controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple custom attribute to annotate the controllers that I want to group and used the `TagActionsBy` method when registering the Swashbuckle.

```
builder.Services
    .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.TagActionsBy(api =>
        {
            if (api.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
            {
                var group = actionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GroupTagAttribute), true)
                    .Cast<GroupTagAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

                return group != null
                    ? new List<string> {group.Name}
                    : new List<string> {actionDescriptor.ControllerName};
            }

            throw new NullReferenceException("Couldn't find the group name");
        });
        // the rest of the configuration
    });
```

The `GroupTagAttribute`

```
public class GroupTagAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ApiGroupAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer really helped me get to where I was trying to. I ended up using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.TagsAttribute which allows you to have multiple tags per action.