# How to configure swagger in netcore3.1 web application with an area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, webapi

Im writing web service endpoints (as an area:'api') in my mvc web application(not webapi).
Is there somebody who can tell me how to config swagger with an area?

```
services.AddSwaggerGen();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("api/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MY API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "api";
});
```

Comment: If I Have understood your point, maybe this is the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506078/12781348

Comment: i doesn't work for me. but tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can write an extended class to get the `AreaName`, like this:

```
  public static class ApiDescriptionExtension
    {
        public static List<string> GetAreaName(this ApiDescription description)
        {
            string areaName = description.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["Area"];
            List<string> areaList = new List<string>();
            areaList.Add(areaName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
            {
                description.RelativePath = $"{description.RelativePath}";
            }
            return areaList;
        }
    }
```

Then in your `StartUp`(Add this code:`c.TagActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.GetAreaName());`):

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
               //...
            });

            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo
            {
               //...
            });
            c.TagActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.GetAreaName());

        });
```

Remember to configure your Area routing:

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "Area",
            pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
```

In your `ApiController` in your `Area`:

Example:

```
[Area("Area")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("v1/Area/api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<TodoItem>> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: great answer. thank you so much 